# help connecting wirelessly lubuntu 12.04

Tags: wireless, networking, firmware

Okay, so you will probably think I'm crazy, but I had so many problems with Windows, I decided to reinstall XP...fat lotta good that did. So I tried lubuntu, not knowing anything about it or programming.

It works pretty well too, but for some reason I can't get a wireless connection. I've read other posts, and get lost in the technical jargon. I don't even know what a gui master controller utility, or whatever they said, is. "Wireless networks" is greyed out, as is "device not ready (firmware missing)" when I put my mouse over the networks icon in my tray.

How do I get this thing to connect without being tied to the ethernet cable I am currently using? Details and laymen's terms, please. This is a Dell latitude d600. Beyond that, I couldn't give any more detail about the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

The driver for the Dell Latitude D600 could be one of this 2:

BCM4306 - pci:id **14e4:4324**

BCM4309 - pci:id **14e4:4324 (rev 02)**

As seen in [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcm43xx/60395#60395) it shows that 14e4:4324 can work with the `linux-firmware-nonfree` package. Just follow the guide in that question to solve it. I won't mark this as duplicate of that one because you have a 50% chance of having the other version, the **14e4:4324 (rev 02)** so I will wait to see how it goes with the recommendation and if you can run `lspci -nn -d 14e4:` on the terminal to see which version you actually have and to which package you actually need to install.

In the case it is the **rev 02** before accepting this answer, please respond so we can added to the long list of Broadcom drivers in a comment.